# Cannot Read Property “path” of Undefined

Tags: node.js, multer

I've looked at a lot of answer for this same question, but I haven't found a working solution yet. I am trying to make a web app that you can upload files to using express and multer, and I am having a problem that no files are being uploaded and 'path' is always undefined.

```
    destination : (req, file, cb) => cb(null,'public/images'),
    filename : (req, file, cb) => cb(null, file.originalname)
})

app.use(multer({ storage : imageStorage}).single('imageFile'));

let id = 1;


app.get('/posts',async (req,res) =>{
    let posts = await Post.find();
    res.send(posts);
});

app.post('/posts',async (req,res) =>{
    let reqBody = req.body;
    let imgPath;
    if(reqBody.imageURL){
        imgPath = reqBody.imageURL;
    }else{
        imgPath = req.file.path.substring(req.file.path.indexOf('/'), req.file.path.length);
    }


    let nwePost = new Post({
        id : id++,
        title : reqBody.title,
        date : new Date(),
        description : reqBody.description,
        text : reqBody.text,
        district : reqBody.district,
        imageURL : imgPath
    })

    await nwePost.save();
    res.send('Created');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not testing properties before accessing them. The issue is here:

```
const imgPath = req.file.path.substring(req.file.path.indexOf('/'), 
         req.file.path.length);
```

You should always test properties to validate that they exist, before doing deep access. This will protect your applications from these errors, which are technically called "Null Pointer Exceptions". It is a problem in JS.

So you should always do something like:

```
const maybeFile = req.file 
const maybePath = maybeFile ? maybeFile.path : undefined
const maybeImgPath = maybePath ? maybePath.substring(path.indexOf('/'), path.length) : undefined
// now maybeImgPath is either a path or undefined. Test it before using it
```

That explains the error message.

For the underlying issue:

The problem is with the shape of `req`. Use `console.log(req)` to inspect it.

Either your assumption about its shape is incorrect, or else you are not passing in the data correctly in the request when you post it from the front-end.

Either way, you should start defensively programming against `undefined` in your code as you go.

Comment: can you please tell me what will be solution.?

Comment: I just did. Did you change your code to guard against `undefined` and add the `console.log` statement to inspect `req`?

Comment: Yes. But image src is undefined. I am not getting the image path

Comment: <img src="undefined" alt="Saint Martin" class="card-img-top">

Answer (score 0):

You've better test both your backend and frontend.

1. For your Frontend: Are you using a `new FormData()` as your request body? If not do so & use the newly created formData object to append values to form fields
   https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData
2. For your backend please `console.log(req.file.path)` in the `else block` inside `app.post('/post',...)` route

and I suggest you use something  like this for your file name:
`filename : (req, file, cb) => cb(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname)`
in `multer.diskstorage` to avoid duplicate file names.

Comment: i used new FormData(). and also consol .log. Now its says file is not defined

Comment: sorry! my bad. I meant console.log(req.file.path)

Comment: public\images\seaport-during-daytime-132037.jpg  I am also getting the backslash instead of forward slash

Comment: It shows that you're getting the file correctly and you're making it to else block and all is good.
backslash is because you're using windows.
what do you expect the imgPath to be?

Comment: It should be /images/image name.extention

Comment: /images/seaport-during-daytime-132037.jpg like this one

Comment: you can concatenate: '/images/' + req.file.originalname
so:
imgPath = '/images/' + req.file.originalname

Comment: Thanks its works. But when i enter the url to the input field it says ```TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined``` What should I do for that option

Comment: `imgPath = '/images/' + req.file.filename` is the correct answer

Comment: yes its works when i chose a file from desktop. But it does not works when i enter an URL to the input field. it says TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined . I have two options chose file or enter an URL

Comment: You're welcome! 
If you're using the `if(reqBody.imageURL){
     //...
    }else{
//...
    }`
 as you did in the first place there shouldn't be such an error. check the spelling of your input field name

Comment: It's a good idea to open a new question with both your frontend and backend code. sharing your code on GitHub is a good idea I guess